# ElFinder - Unable to connect to backend

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, codeigniter-2, elfinder

I'm trying to integrate CKeditor and Elfinder into my Codeigniter application. 
CKeditor works fine but whatever file browser I try to use, I get `server error`.
Currently I'm trying to work with Elfinder, and I get `Unable to connect to backend` error.

I already did what it said in wiki article, but I can't seem to get past this.
I should also mention that `connector.php` returns `server error` and this is same problem that I already had with Kcfinder.

Comment: What is your folder structure? And permissions?

Comment: `application` folder and `editor` folder are at project root. 
Inside `editor` folder I have `ckeditor` (775) and `elfinder` (775) folders. 
Inside `elfinder` folder I have `files` (755) folder.